# Edit global variable in sub-shell

Tags: bash, shell, centos8

In the following script, I am using bash to check whether users own their home directories as part of the CIS CentOS 8 Benchmark (6.2.8).

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -E -v '^(halt|sync|shutdown)' /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($7 != "'"$(which nologin)"'" && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' | while read user dir; do
 if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
 else
        owner=$(stat -L -c "%U" "$dir")
        if [ "$owner" != "$user" ]; then
                echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user is owned by $owner."
        fi
 fi
done
```

I am trying to print something if there are no errors using a global variable. The following is my attempt at it:

```
correct=true
grep -E -v '^(halt|sync|shutdown)' /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($7 != "'"$(which nologin)"'" && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' | while read user dir; do
 if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
        correct=false
 else
        owner=$(stat -L -c "%U" "$dir")
        if [ "$owner" != "$user" ]; then
                echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user is owned by $owner."
                correct=false
        fi
 fi
done
if [ "$correct" = true ]; then
        echo "Non-compliance?: No"
        echo "Details: All users own their home directories."
        echo
fi
```

However, the global variable, `correct`, will not change regardless of what happens in the `while` loop because it is in multiple sub-shells.
I read up about this and noticed people using "here strings" so that the `while` loop will not be in a sub-shell. However, for my case I have multiple pipes (possibly might even add more for other scripts), so I don't really know how to make it do what I want here.

How can I get results information out of a loop
so I can display summary information after the loop completes
when the loop is executed in a sub-shell?

Comment: Please replace all images with its text.

Comment: Now you replaced the images with text, but there is a different script in the image, compared to the text....

Comment: Sorry, the second image comes from my VM, it is not too convenient to replace it with text. But it is the same as the first script except I added the ```correct``` global variable and some output if compliant.

Comment: Yoy can put at beginning of script `shopt -s lastpipe` which allows to run last command of pipe in the current shell.

Comment: May I know what does the ```shopt -s lastpipe``` command do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code/design fails on an edge case:
   user Horatio Altman might have a username of `haltman`. 
   Your code would ignore him since his name begins with `halt`. 
   You should use a regular expression
   of `'^(halt|sync|shutdown):'`. 
   Note the colon at the end — this will match only lines that have `halt`,
   `sync` or `shutdown` as the first field in the **`:`**-delimited file.
2. `awk` is a very powerful program. 
   You almost never need to combine it with anything like `grep` or `sed`; 
   `awk` can do (pretty much?) anything they can do. 
   In your script, we can eliminate the `grep`
   and put the `halt` / `sync` / `shutdown` logic into `awk`:

   ```
   awk -F: '($1 != "halt" && $1 != "sync" && $1 != "shutdown" && $7 != "'"$(which nologin)"'" && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' /etc/passwd |
           while read user dir; do
                     ︙
   ```

   Since `$1` means everything up to the first colon (since we have `-F:`)
   and we are doing simple string equality checking
   (rather than regexp matching),
   we don’t need the `^` at the beginning or the **`:`** at the end. 
   Also note that we can add an <kbd>Enter</kbd> after a `|`
   without needing a backslash.
3. The triple quote character is messy; it’s hard to read,
   and easy to get wrong, especially when you edit the script a year from now. 
   A cleaner way to inject information into an `awk` script is to use a variable:

   ```
   awk -F: -v nl="$(which nologin)" \
               '($1 != "halt" && $1 != "sync" && $1 != "shutdown" && $7 != nl && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' /etc/passwd |
           while read user dir; do
                     ︙
   ```

   Here I created an awk variable called `nl`
   with the value of `$(which nologin)`,
   and then used that variable in the comparison against `$7`. 
   (Also I broke that very long line with a backslash, for readability.)
4. OK, now I’ll start really answering the question. 
   As you understand, the problem with your script is that
   it sets the `correct` variable inside a subshell
   and then tries to access it outside the subshell. 
   One solution is to move the statement(s) that access the variable
   ***into** the subshell.* 
   You might think that this is infeasible,
   since the subshell is the `while` loop,
   and you don’t want to print the success message inside the loop. 
   The trick is to force a larger subshell:

   ```
   correct=true
   awk -F: -v nl="$(which nologin)" \
               '($1 != "halt" && $1 != "sync" && $1 != "shutdown" && $7 != nl && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' /etc/passwd |
       (
           while read user dir; do
                   if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
                           echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user does not exist."
                           correct=false
                   else
                           owner=$(stat -L -c "%U" "$dir")
                           if [ "$owner" != "$user" ]; then
                                   echo "The home directory ($dir) of user $user is owned by $owner."
                                   correct=false
                           fi
                   fi
           done
           if [ "$correct" = true ]; then
                   echo "All users own their home directories."
           fi
       )
   ```

   I added parentheses to force a subshell that encompasses
   the `while` loop and the `if-then` statement. 
   I put the parentheses on separate lines for readability;
   you can move them onto the preceding line or the following line
   if you want to minimize your line count. 
   (The next code block demonstrates this.)
5. But what if you want to use the value of `$correct`
   at some point much later in the script? 
   You don’t want to move large, unrelated chunks of code into the subshell
   just so you can use this trick. 
   Well, my next trick is to pass information out of the subshell
   by using its exit status:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   correct=true
   awk -F: -v nl="$(which nologin)" \
               '($1 != "halt" && $1 != "sync" && $1 != "shutdown" && $7 != nl && $7 != "/bin/false") { print $1 " " $6 }' /etc/passwd |
           (while read user dir; do
                   if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
                         ︙
                   fi
           done
           if [ "$correct" = true ]; then
                   exit 0
           else
                   exit 1
           fi)
   if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
           correct=true
   else
           correct=false
   fi
             ︙                         # Possibly much later in the script.
   if [ "$correct" = true ]; then
           echo "All users own their home directories."
   fi
   ```

   In theory, exit codes can range from 0 to 255,
   although it’s best to limit yourself to the 0-125 range. 
   See [What is the min and max values of exit codes in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418784/23408#418802)

Answer (score 1):

This [How is return handled in a function while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910112/how-is-return-handled-in-a-function-while-loop), and some rewriting led to this script, which can return `false`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=/tmp/$$
grep -E -v '^(halt|sync|shutdown)' /etc/passwd | 
   grep -E -v '/bin/false$|nologin$' | 
   awk -F: '{ print $1,$6 }' > $tmp

correct=true

while read user dir; do
  #echo $user $dir
  if [ ! -d $dir ];
  then
     echo "Dir ($dir) does not exist"
     correct=false
  fi
  owner=$(stat -L -c "$user" "$dir")
  if [ "$owner" != "$user" ];
  then
     echo "home directory for user ($user) is owned by ($owner)"
     correct=false
  fi
done < $tmp

rm $tmp

echo "CORRECT: $correct"
```